# Remove Node from DOM

Tags: javascript

Noob question alert! I am working on a basic clock that updates every second, but its not updating because I get Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8. Basically i just need to change the removeChild() at the end of the function to something else, but I don't know what to change it to. I want to remove the `<p class="time">` that is being created.

```
function spitTime() {
    var clock = new Date();
    var hours = clock.getHours();
    var minutes = clock.getMinutes();
    var seconds = clock.getSeconds();

    if (minutes <= 9) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    if (seconds <= 9) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    var displayTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    var newTimeElem = document.createElement("p");
    newTimeElem.className = "time";
    var timeText = document.createTextNode(displayTime);
    newTimeElem.appendChild(timeText);
    document.getElementById("timePlace").appendChild(newTimeElem);
    document.getElementById("timePlace").removeChild();
}
```

relevant HTML:

```
<div class="clock">
    <span id="timePlace"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just change the existing element's content directly?

Comment: How would I know without your HTML?

Comment: Why would you create it, add a text node, append it, then remove it immediately? How about describing what you're ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you're just trying to change the text, do this `document.getElementById("timePlace").firstChild.data = displayTime`. If the element is initially loaded with no content, put some temporary text content there so that there's a `firstChild` when page loads.

Comment: @amnotiam my, that's a way-that-will-work-once-in-a-while! :-)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: ...hmmm, not following you. If by once-in-a-while, you mean every-time, then I must agree. :-) Though I should point out that the temp text content mustn't be whitespace-only for IE sake *(of course)*.

Comment: Not IE sake, you might need `nextSibling` almost all the time, since people usually put some spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, you don't want to remove a child, you want to change the text of an existing element.

For this, you can use `textContent`:

```
document.getElementById( 'timePlace' ).textContent = displayTime;
```

It is to be noted that this isn't cross browser. IE8 and below work with `innerText` instead. A quick hack to use is this way:

```
var timePlace = document.getElementById( 'timePlace' );
if ( 'textContent' in timePlace ) {
    timePlace.textContent = displayTime;
}
else {
    timePlace.innerText = displayTime;
}
```

However, it is a hack. It will work nicely for your case, but don't rely on this.

If you really want cross browser compatibility, you're using jQuery by the way (or any other library like this). jQuery way to change text:

```
$( '#timePlace' ).text( displayTime );
```

It uses `nodeValue`, the only real cross-browser way to deal with text. It has to do this recursively though, because it is only available on `textNodes`. It is equivalent to using `data` (as @amnotiam does in the comments of your question).

Comment: What would be the best way to give a class to the displayTime, or put it in a p tag?

Comment: `document.getElementById( 'timePlace' ).className = ''`? Is that what you want? To put it in a p tag, use `appendChild`.

Comment: okay cool thanks, sorry for the simple questions, but also the markup on inspect element looks very odd, its like `<span id="timePlace">11:26:19</span>"11:26:45"</span>` do you know why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying a child node to be removed.

**[Node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild)**

```
var oldChild = element.removeChild(child);
element.removeChild(child);
```

- child is the child node to be removed from the DOM.
- element is the parent node of child.
- oldChild holds a reference to the removed child node. oldChild == child

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `timePlace`element itself:

```
document
    .getElementById("timePlace")
    .parentNode
    .removeChild(document.getElementById('timePlace'));
```

Assuming this is the intent, this works by by finding the relevant element/node (`getElementById()`), moving to the `parentNode` of that element and then removing the element from the parent (since `removeChild()` both expects a DOM node to be passed to it, *and* removes a child node of the current element/node).

---

Updated according to the comment from OP (below), simply use:

```
newTimeElem.parentNode.removeChild(newTimeElem);
```

References:

- [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild).

Comment: I want to remove the <p class="time"> that is being created.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function spitTime() {
            var clock = new Date();
            var hours = clock.getHours();
            var minutes = clock.getMinutes();
            var seconds = clock.getSeconds();

            if (minutes <= 9) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }

            if (seconds <= 9) {
                seconds = "0" + seconds;
            }

            var displayTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            var newTimeElem = document.createElement("p");
            newTimeElem.className = "time";
            var timeText = document.createTextNode(displayTime);
            newTimeElem.appendChild(timeText);
            $('#timePlace').children('.time').remove();
            document.getElementById("timePlace").appendChild(newTimeElem);
            setTimeout('spitTime()', 100);
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout('spitTime()', 100);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clock">
        <span id="timePlace"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Link: http://lib-eguide.nus.edu.sg/test1.php

Comment: there are two problems in ur code, 1- ur last line, 2- logical error.

Comment: You're adding this comment to your own answer?!

Comment: yup, actually i m not quite familiar with stakeoverflow, since first he add child then he wants to delete child, logically he needs to first remove the previous added one, then add a new one.

Comment: Add this comment on the question then, not your answer :)

Comment: But your code indeed won't work. And since he's asking for plain javascript, jQuery just won't do :-)

Comment: correcnt just need to convert jquery with javascript :D, But it will be work if he has jQuery. What do u think? do u think this logical problem exit or no?

Comment: oh one more thing, i do not have access permission to add comment in this question, just i can add to my own answer :D

Comment: Well, see my answer to see what he expected :)

Comment: well, you are right, it works , but also my answer is right? Actually i has more experience with Jquery in compare to javascript.

Comment: Your answer is wrong because it turned out he didn't want to remove any DOM elements, he just wanted to change the text. Getting some experience in javascript will only increase your jQuery level by the way :)

Comment: if you want to put it question look like this by literate, you are right, but how about if u consider whether it solved the real problem or no :) never mind

Comment: Uh? I didn't understand what you said!

Comment: please have a look whether it works or no :  http://lib-eguide.nus.edu.sg/test1.php

Answer (score 0):

```
while (timePlace.firstChild) {
    timePlace.removeChild(timePlace.firstChild)
}
```

Is what I was going for, though it might be better just to edit the content, this works for me very well.